# Mongodb Aggregate function with reference to another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections

**Persons**

```
{
  "name": "Tom",
  "car_id": "55b73e3e8ead0e220d8b45f3"
}
...
```

**Cars**

```
{
  "model": "BMW",
  "car_id": "55b73e3e8ead0e220d8b45f3"
}
...
```

How can i do a query such that i can get the following results (for example)

```
BMW : 2
Toyota: 3
```

Below is my aggregate function. I can get it the data out, however it does the car _id instead of the model name.

```
db.persons.aggregate([
   {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            car_Id: "$car_id",
        },

        carsCount: {$sum: 1}
    },
  },
]);
```

Appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

you can aggregate internally in one collection with one query. I would suggest to keep aggregated data like that or similar:

```
{
    car_id: 273645jhg2f52345hj3564jh6
    sum: 4
}
```

And replace ID with name when you will need to expose data to the user.

Comment: hi thanks. is it best practice to always maintain the sum key attribute in the document?

Comment: that is up to you =). But if you are doing aggregation that the idea to have some value field and SUM for me looks ok. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/